# One to many model POST using API View

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-views

I have this model

[image: One to many model]

I want to POST this to my location endpoint

```
{
"location": {
    "latitude": "1.23456789",
    "longitude": "1.23456789",
    "resources": [
        {
            "url": "s3/locations/1/es.mp4",
            "name": "lorem_1"
        },
        {
            "url": "s3/locations/1/en.mp4",
            "name": "lorem2"
        }
    ]
}
```

My goal is to add a location with **many resources** and to do it through a **single locations endpoint** using API Views

This is my view:

```
class LocationView(APIView, api_settings.DEFAULT_PAGINATION_CLASS):
    queryset = Location.objects.all()
    permission_classes = (permissions.AllowAny, )
    serializer_class = LocationSerializer

    def post(self, request):
        serializer = self.serializer_class(data=request.data)
        serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
        serializer.save()
        return response.Response(request.data)
```

And this is my serializer:

```
class LocationSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
resources = ResourceSerializer(source='resource_set', many=True, read_only=True)

class Meta:
    model = Location
    fields = ('id', 'latitude', 'longitude', 'resources')
```

Comment: Have a look [here](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/#writable-nested-serializers) for an example from the drf docs on how to do this with your serializers

Comment: The resources, that you're now uploading, are already existing ones?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nested serializers are read-only, you will need to override the `create` method.

```py
# serializers.py

class LocationSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    resources = ResourceSerializer(source='resource_set', many=True, read_only=True)

    def create(self, validated_data):
        resources_data = validated_data.pop('resources')
        location = Location.objects.create(**validated_data)
        for resource in resources_data:
            Resource.objects.create(location=location, **resource)
        return location

    class Meta:
        model = Location
        fields = ('id', 'latitude', 'longitude', 'resources')
```

The same goes for the `update` method.
More details in [the official documentation](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/#writable-nested-serializers).